# Django run code on application start but not on migrations

Tags: python, django

Hi I want to start a background thread that runs the first time my Application is running. I  have implemeted it using the `ready()`  function of the application config.

```
class MyappConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'myApp'
    
    def ready(self):
        try:
            thread = threading.Thread(target=xxxx)
        except:
            pass
```

Problem is this method is called when Django runs its migrations as well, which it should not. How can I prevent this from happening.

I have tried using Django background tasks but it simply wont run the task at all

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with that thread? It's very likely that this is not the right tool for the task at hand.

Comment: I want this thread to sync some data in the background.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific. What data? Coming from where? Changed in what circumstances?

Comment: My app needs to sync data with an external API when a action is performed. But this external API is not guranteed to be UP all the time. Hence I have to upload all failed sync attempts to this API later on. i was hoping to use a background process to do this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can avoid executing code if the script is called with "python manage.py [migrate]":

```
import sys
if not 'manage.py' in sys.argv:
    ....
```

Comment: Tx will give it a try

Comment: What about `django-admin`? You could instead use `if not 'migrate' in sys.argv`

Comment: I did as `    if not 'runserver' in sys.argv:
        return`

Comment: @WilletteLynch> then you have a bug in your application. And the bad kind of bug: bugs that will only happen on production.

Comment: I agree with spectras. In the original post you wanted to make an exception for migrations, though, and in this case I think it is ok.

Comment: Why would apps need to be started on migrations and other commands?

Answer (score 2):

I found the best way to do it was to check if `runserver` was in the `sys.argv`

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
import sys

class config(AppConfig):
    name = 'appName'
    if 'runserver' in sys.argv:
        do_main_thread()
```

this works better then `manage.py` because the argument is in every command i used to `migrate`, `makemigrations` and `runserver`.

Answer (score 1):

Prepared my version of how to avoid starting custom thread in background when Django app started.

For example if you are setting webhooks or pushing another service. And want to avoid that during migrations or any other command except of `manage.py runserver` and starting web-server using `gunicorn`.

```py
import logging
import sys
from django.apps import AppConfig

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class config(AppConfig):

    def ready(self):
        if not sys.argv[0].endswith('gunicorn') and \
                sys.argv[0].endswith('manage.py') and 'runserver' not in sys.argv:
            logger.debug('Not starting extra threads here.')
            return

        do_start_new_threads()
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers check whether you are running `manage.py` or `runserver`. A more accurate way would be to check whether you are running `migrate`:

Example:

```py
class BadgesConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'badges'

    def ready(self):
        if 'migrate' in sys.argv: # <<<--- Here
            return
        # What to do if not migrate
```